# How to remove header and menu from customtaskpane for outlook addin

Tags: outlook-addin

I am creating addin for outlook. I add custom usercontrol on custom task pane. I just want to know that is there any approach to hide the the header text and custom menu ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

No, the caption bar with the close button cannot be hidden.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you please suggest me any other approach so i can design the addin without these button. I had seen at salesforce addin or contact monkey addin they had not the caption bar.

Comment: They might not be using a task panes - see https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/OlAdjacentWindows/